# Part of strings that are case-sensitive from a given column

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have searched for a solution for hours, and could not find a way to do this (seems impossible). I collect user's data like user agent, referral values etc.

So, some referral values contain query strings of searched keywords where sometimes the searched keywords are upper-case, and sometimes, are lower-case or mixed.

What I would like to achieve is only the fields that their referral value has upper case strings.

So, for example, I want to get only fields like this:

```
bing.com/?q=HOW+TO+PLAY+TENNIS
```

but not fields like this:

```
bing.com/?q=how+to+play+tennis
```

or like this (mixed case)

```
bing.com/?q=HOW+to+play+tennis
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found the default collation is case insensitive. However you can specify a case sensitive collation and this will work as you expect:

```
col_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'bing.com/?q=HOW+TO+PLAY+TENNIS'
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, however, I dont really know what the query string is, so I cannot use LIKE 'bing.com....'

Comment: @MrBlackJack Can you post the code that you are using at the moment? All that's needed is to alter the current query to add the `COLLATE latin1_general_cs`.

Comment: @MrBlackJack Ah, sorry I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right.
What about selecting all queries and filter them afterwards via preg_match_all.
Use a pattern like this:

```
'/.*?\/\?q=[A-Z+]+/'
```

Its not tested and should you give a idea.